# Writing Stream to file - File becomes corrupted (.xls, .doc)

Tags: c#, file-upload, filestream

I am using chunk upload to upload a folder containing multiple files.

```
$("#folders").kendoUpload({
                    async: {
                        saveUrl: baseAddrs + "/" + "DragAndDrop/ChunkSave",
                        removeUrl: baseAddrs + "/" + "DragAndDrop/remove",
                        chunkSize: 31457280, // ~30 MB
                        autoUpload: true,
                        concurrent: true
                    },
                    upload: onUpload,
                    directory: true,
                    directoryDrop: true,
                    complete: onComplete,
                    success: onFileSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });
```

I am using AppendtoFile logic in case if file is greater than 30 MB it will split and upload.
Example-> If a file of 50 MB is uploaded, it will break into 2 chunks and first 30 MB of data will be written to the file and in the next iteration 20 MB will be written. I first write this file to a temp location , for the first run file size will be 30 MB and for final chunk it will append next 20 MB to the file and now the file will become 50 MB. Now when i try to open this file from temp location it says file is corrupted or does not have valid extension. Extension is valid i verified it. .xls, .docx, .pptx, .jpg this file give same error message but .pdf works like a charm without any issue. Even if file size is under 30 MB then also above extensions does not work, only .pdf works. What i am missing ?

```
 public string AppendChunkData(string filePath, ChunkMetaData metaData)
        {
            var uniqueUploadId = metaData.UploadUid;            
            string BaseFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string path = Server.MapPath(UploadTemp + "/ChunkUpload");
            string newpath =  Path.Combine(path, uniqueUploadId + BaseFileName);
            byte[] byteArray = StreamToByteArray(Request.InputStream);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(newpath, FileMode.Append))
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            
            return newpath;
        }

 private byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream srcFile)
        {
            srcFile.Position = 0;//faster than seek when dealing with an absolute position.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[srcFile.Length];
            srcFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            return buffer;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, problem was on Request.InputStream. I was not passing the correct stream. After i passed the correct stream. It is working for all kinds of files.